# Regex to filter the value and show less than required version number

Tags: regex, version, text-processing

We have docker tags with below versions, please help to share the regex pattern to filter the records that are older than below values.  For example, should show old tags - `23.0.0.17` and older, `23.0.0.17_acme.17.xxxxxxx` and older, etc?

```
23.0.0.18
23.0.0.18_acme.18.xxxxxxx
23.1.0.11
23.1.0.11_acme.11.xxxxxxx
```

Comment: Which language or shell / OS are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Digit computation is better done in your favorite language

Comment: @GillesQuénot: just general regex which can be used any where ...which we use as java script.

Comment: There's no such thing as "general regex"... Different engines have different syntaxes. It's also not really a good job for regex, although it's achievable.

Answer (score 1):

To get versions `23.0.0.17` or older, you could use this for JS:

```
^((23\.0\.0\.(1[0-7]|\d))|((2[0-2]|1\d|\d)\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+))\S*
```

As I said in comment below question, this is not really a job for regexes, although you can play around and build some. You basically have to consider all the options for digit combinations - the 1st alternative matches all possible `23` versions and the 2nd matches anything below.

A much better idea is to use libraries that are built to compare versions or write a function on your own,like https://stackoverflow.com/a/16187766/7264739